# How to get all possible combinations of two different lists?

Tags: python, list, statistics, combinations, permutation

I'm having so much trouble understanding my issue:

I got 2 lists:

```
from = ['A', 'B', 'C']
to = ['D', 'E', 'F']
```

I need to produce a matrix that combines each item from one list to the other as such:

```
final = [[['A', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'F']],
         [['A', 'D'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'E']],
         [['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'D']],
         [['A', 'E'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'F']],
         [['A', 'F'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'E']],
         [['A', 'F'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'D']]]
```

I was trying to do this with this:

```
for i in range(len(initial)):
    for j in range(len(transformed)):
        self.semantic_networks[j][i][0] = self.initial_figure[i]['name']
        self.semantic_networks[i][j][1] = self.transformed_figure[(j + i) % len(self.transformed_figure)]['name']
```

But, I'm getting only the top:

```
[['A', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'F']]
[['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'D']]
[['A', 'F'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'E']]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

What am I trying to get? Combination? Permutation? Combination of combinations??

Any hints???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) on the second list and then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) each permutation with first list.

```
from itertools import permutations

lst1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lst2 = ['D', 'E', 'F']

for p in permutations(lst2):
    print zip(lst1, p)
#
[('A', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'F')]
[('A', 'D'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'E')]
[('A', 'E'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'F')]
[('A', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'D')]
[('A', 'F'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'E')]
[('A', 'F'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D')]
```

Comment: OMG this is exactly what I was looking for... Thank you! So simple and I have spent hours on the same thing, can't believe.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want the combination of all possible permutations:

```
import itertools
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = ['D', 'E', 'F']
items = zip(itertools.permutations(a), itertools.permutations(b))
```

Comment: Not quite, it is not the final result I'm looking for.

Comment: @mimoralea: I know, but from here you can create the final result.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: The answer is somewhat poor. Neither does it solve the original problem, nor does it show how to proceed from a list of tuples of two permutations. [((a,b,c), (d,e,f)), ...]